# exec() fails randomly with strange behaviour

Tags: php, ubuntu, exec

I'm trying to use exec() to do a batch PDF to JPEG conversation using pdftoppm utility on an Ubuntu-based server.
The main part of PHP script `converter.php` is:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $PDF_pageCount; $i++){
    exec("pdftoppm -jpeg -f $i -l $i '$PDF_source' '$PNG_output' 2>&1", $Output, $Status);
    sleep(1); //  To simulate delay and let the other instance to run while this one is inside the loop.
}
```

Now, take two files for example:

- ./A/source_file.pdf
- ./B/source_file.pdf

These files are exist on their place on the disk.
The parent folders' (`A/` & `B/`) owner and permissions are:

> UID: www-data, GID: www-data, Permission: 755

The files' (both `source_file.pdf`) owner and permissions are:

> UID: www-data, GID: www-data, Permission: 644

There code works file when only one instance of script is being run and generates the outputs without any problem. For example, with `$PDF_source = './A/source_file.pdf'`. All pages will convert to JPEG files successfully.

But when the second instance of script runs, exec() function works on only one of them and in other one, it produces the following error with exit status 1:

```
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '/path/to/source_file.pdf': No such file or directory.
```

In other word, one of files will be converted to JPEG and the other one (although the first one might be ended already) will produce the error on output.
Note that all of the paths to files are correct and files exist.

Also note that the script is being run from CLI with the following command in a cronjob (but might be executed from a standard web request too):

```
/path/to/php -q /path/to/converter.php
```

I tried to prevent running more than one instance of file in a time with the following code in the beginning of the script:

```
class Lock{
    private $fp;
    function __construct(){
        $this->fp=fopen(__FILE__,'r');
        if (!flock($this->fp,LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) {
            die('ARN'.PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
    function __destruct(){
        flock($this->fp,LOCK_UN);
        fclose($this->fp);
    }
}

$lock=new Lock();
```

What is the problem exactly? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just added `__DIR__.'/'.` before inputs and it's working now.

But I still want to find out why it was working before adding the directory in the first execution of script?